# simpleXML creating a foreach

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreach and simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154689/foreach-and-simplexml)

I have got my XML document loading correct but I am unsure how I can create a simple foreach were I can have `[PictureHref]` `[Title]` and `[PriceDisplay]` loaded for each item given in the feed.

I cannot find a clear example in the documentation.

[XML Example](http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml)

Currently my PHP code consists of the following:

```
$mainUrl = 'http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/{id}/Listings/All.xml';
$xmlFeed = simplexml_load_file($mainUrl);
```

XML

```
<Listings xmlns="http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TotalCount>1</TotalCount>
    <Page>1</Page>
    <PageSize>1</PageSize>
    <List>
        <Listing>
            <ListingId>527496168</ListingId>
            <Title>Clifftop Resort style Living with stunning aspect</Title>
            <Category>0350-5748-3399-</Category>
            <StartPrice>0</StartPrice>
            <StartDate>2012-10-26T21:24:47.073Z</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2012-12-21T21:24:47.073Z</EndDate>
            <ListingLength i:nil="true" />
            <HasGallery>true</HasGallery>
            <AsAt>2012-10-28T22:48:47.409946Z</AsAt>
            <CategoryPath>/Trade-me-property/Residential/For-sale</CategoryPath>
            <PictureHref>http://images.trademe.co.nz/photoserver/thumb/10/239043710.jpg</PictureHref>
            <RegionId>2</RegionId>
            <Region>Auckland</Region>
            <Suburb>North Shore</Suburb>
            <NoteDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</NoteDate>
            <ReserveState>NotApplicable</ReserveState>
            <IsClassified>true</IsClassified>
            <GeographicLocation>
                <Latitude>-36.5681333</Latitude>
                <Longitude>174.6936265</Longitude>
                <Northing>5951700</Northing>
                <Easting>1751547</Easting>
                <Accuracy>Address</Accuracy>
            </GeographicLocation>
            <PriceDisplay>To be auctioned</PriceDisplay>
        </Listing>
    </List>
</Listings>
```

Comment: Can we see an example of your XML?

Comment: @SomeKittens sure http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml

Comment: @Jess McKenzie i think you should delete the last comment that should not be a public information ... i would edit your question with the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
$url = simplexml_load_file("__YOUR__URL___");
$listing = $url->List->Listing;

echo "<pre>";
echo $listing->PictureHref, PHP_EOL;
echo $listing->Title, PHP_EOL;
echo $listing->PriceDisplay, PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'd recommend the use of DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML, here's how you'd do that in SimpleXML:

```
$data = array();

foreach($xmlFeed->List as $item) {
    $data[] = array(
        (string) $item->Listing->PictureHref,
        (string) $item->Listing->Title,
        (string) $item->Listing->PriceDisplay
    );
}
```

You can see it (sorta, I had to change some things) [at CodePad](http://codepad.org/ITbAnxsw)

Comment: Thanks,  How could I turn the 3 items into a $var that I could echo in the appropriate places?

Comment: It's already a var in `$data`, which is an array.  Each index of the array is a List item containing the three pieces of data that you wanted.