# how to get array data from XML loop foreach

Tags: php, arrays, xml, loops, foreach

I have sparql output in XML like this : `

```
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
<head>
    <variable name="Keyword2"/>
</head>
<results ordered="false" distinct="false">
    <result>
        <binding name="Keyword2">
            <uri>http://www.semanticweb.org/g/ontologies/2010/0/OntologiBatikTanty#Soga_Jawa</uri>
        </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
        <binding name="Keyword2">
            <uri>http://www.semanticweb.org/g/ontologies/2010/0/OntologiBatikTanty#Warna_Alami</uri>
        </binding>
    </result>
</results>
</sparql>
```

`

I make foreach looping in php like this: `

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die ("error cannot create object");
$results = $xml->results->result;
$jumlah=count($results);
echo "Total hasil pencarian : $jumlah <br><br>";
//$keyword2=array();
$output=array();
foreach($xml->results->result as $nodes){
$jumlah=count($nodes);
    foreach ($nodes->binding as $key =>$node) {
      $output=$node->uri;
      echo $output;
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo $keyword=substr($output,66);
      echo "<br><br>";  
    }
    }
    echo"<hr>";
    echo $keyword[0];
```

`

My question is how to acces the data array from outside looping. for example i want to acces index[0]. but the output only "W" it should be "Soga_Jawa"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use foreach with PHP & XML (simplexml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637617/how-to-use-foreach-with-php-xml-simplexml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved your issue please check this code**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die ("error cannot create object");
$results = $xml->results->result;
$jumlah=count($results);
echo "Total hasil pencarian : $jumlah <br><br>";
//$keyword2=array();
$output=array();
$keyword = array();
foreach($xml->results->result as $nodes){
$jumlah=count($nodes);
    foreach ($nodes->binding as $key =>$node) {
      $output=$node->uri;
      echo $output;
      echo "<br><br>";
      echo $keyword[]=substr($output,66);
      echo "<br><br>";  
    }
    }
    echo"<hr>";
    echo $keyword[0];
```

**use keyword as array type and get it to out of loop**