# Display Image from PHP to XML

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to call an image in my PHP to an XML file. I have tried to do this many different ways, but have not had much luck. More specifically, I am trying to call img file variable "Image1" to display. I have also sought tutoring, but the tutor was also somehow stumped on this, so any help is appreciated.

Prompt: (a) Create a XML file which contains the description of at least 3 product names, prices, and image file names.

(b) Load the XML file using Php and generate the shopping items: image, name, price and allow order quantity. Hint: Replace the image file names, item names, and prices with the Php codes.  The Php codes supply the Php variables which were filled by reading the XML file at the beginning of the page.  Then use "echo" verb to show the content of the session variable which contains the file name, item name, and price.   The page should have the file extension  .php.

```html
//My XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<items>
<object>
<Name>CSU Womens T-Shirt</Name>
<Material>3% Polyester / 97% Cotton</Material>
<Price>$23.99</Price>
<image1>C:\Users\erica\OneDrive\Documents\IST450HW\IMGs\csupic.jpg</image1>
</object>
<object>
<Name>CSU Unisex Hat</Name>
<Material>2% Spandex / 98% Cotton</Material>
<Price>$10.99</Price>
</object>
<object>
<Name>CSU Men's T-Shirt</Name>
<Material>5% Polyester / 95% Cotton</Material>
<Price>$19.99</Price>
</object>
</items>

//My PHP
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("Items.xml");

foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": ".$value."</br>";
  }
}
 $result = $xml->$items->$object->$image1;
echo '<img src="'.$result.'" height="100"; "width="100" ;>';
?>
```

Comment: Your URL is a local file system path? Is that your plan?

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with `foreach ($value as $key => $value)`?

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes, I have the image is stored on my local C drive. "C:\Users\erica\OneDrive\Documents\IST450HW\IMGs\csupic.jpg"

Comment: @TimMorton Honestly, I just started learning PHP about 2 days ago. I researched the function for calling values and I wasn't sure if the stated "value" and "key" worked as variables or methods.

Comment: Ah.  The problem that I saw is that you are overwriting `$value`, so your outer loop is immediately trashed.  I don't think you need `$key` in the foreach, because you're iterating through the values (properties).  There are no methods in a simplexml object.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637617/how-to-use-foreach-with-php-xml-simplexml for how to iterate through the xml.

Comment: BTW, You can use print_r or var_dump to see the object's structure.  In your example, you only need to iterate over `<object>`s.  The nested foreach is definitely the wrong direction to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`$xml` will be an object, im not sure why you are looping through it with a foreach, so ill ignore that bit.

To access the element which you're after you need to do it like:

```
$result = $xml->object[0]->image1;
echo '<img src="'.$result.'" height="100" width="100"/>';
```

But your browser won't see that path (or it wont work once you put it elsewhere), so place the image in an accessible location e.g: `./imgs` and then change your xml.

For example:

```
<image1>./imgs/csupic.jpg</image1>
```

Then the resulting `img` tag will look like:

```
<img src="./imgs/csupic.jpg" height="100" width="100"/>
```

The web server will then be able to serve the file without issues.

Comment: Lawrence, so should I create a url for the image or restore it elsewhere on my local drive? Can you explain the process of placing the img in an accessible location? Sorry, I'm trully a noob at this.

Comment: You should be running a webserver (presuming that because your outputting html), so what I mean by accessible is that if you go to the url with your browser `http://localhost/imgs/csupic.jpg` it will load it.. so presuming your using something like XAMMP on windows you would place the image in your webroot `C:/xampp/htdocs/imgs` etc. It seems bewildering that your tutor has not provided you with the foundations of how web sites work before tasking you with working with xml.

Comment: Ok, no that makes sense. I'm currently using XAMMP.

Comment: I called the image from the webserver address, but now I am only seeing a blank square box with a jpg icon display in the corner. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: yeah its not finding it 404 error, check your browsers console.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone re looping with a foreach:  see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6438 (just fyi...)

Comment: @TimMorton sure.. but there is only 1 image1, its not in the other elements.

Answer (score -2):

Try put image file `csupic.jpg` in the same dir of `php` file and if not work change echo line to:

```
echo '<img src="/'.$result.'" height="100"; "width="100" ;>';
```